# Google App Engine Data Base Last Entry

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new with GAE and the language python, and i want to do anything extremely simple, i have the comment box (http://soltexfirstapp.appspot.com) and all i want is, check if someone has write a new comment before the user submit’s the new one and alert him with a box saying “The comment box has a new comment, do you want continue?! Yes or No?”. I am getting so confused with the python syntax, especially with query’s.

My code working...

**shout. py**

```
import webapp2
import datetime
import time
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext.webapp \
 import template



class Shout(db.Model):
    message = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    when = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    who = db.StringProperty()

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        shouts = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Shout ' 
'ORDER BY when ASC')
        values = {
            'shouts': shouts
        }

        # my attempt to make and print the query
        # aaa = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Shout ' 
                            'ORDER BY when DESC LIMIT 1')
        # self.response.out.write('Query is: %s', aaa)

        self.response.out.write(template.render('main.html',values))

    def post(self):
        shout = Shout (
            message = self.request.get('message'),
            who = self.request.get('who'))
        shout.put()
        self.redirect('/')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Comment System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>Cloud Comment System</h1>

{% for shout in shouts %}

<div> 
    <div id="fl">
        {{shout.when}}
        from
        {% ifequal shout.who "" %}
            Anonymous
        {% else %}
        {{shout.who}}
        {% endifequal %}
    </div>

    {{shout.message}}

</div>
{% endfor %}

<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <p>From:<input type="text" name="who" value="" id="who"></p>
    <p>Message:<input type="text" name="message" value="" id="message"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="" value="comment"></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I really appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the outset you should always say what doesn't work in your code, an error etc...  At the moment your request for help is vague.

So I will try and guess what you are after.

In your query you are ordering by ASC (with a date that means the oldest item first).
You should order DESC, newest first as you description suggests you want the most recent comments.

you query should be

```
shouts = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Shout ORDER BY when DESC')
```

In your code you have some extra `'` characters.

You probably don't want to loop and show all Shout's so you should limit the result set with a fetch or something simliar.

Also you are fetching `Shout`s with no sentinal date (ie a date with which to compare with).  I assume from your problem description you want *new* Shout's after a certain date/time.  You need to determine what that date is and use it as a comparison in your query.

Comment: Yea, you are right, i should have said that my code was working. 
Iam using Order by ASC, and the last one is the newest, so its okey for me.
About the extra characters, both ways are right, check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfgO-LXGpTM on minute 6:49 made by google developers.
Thanks for the "fetch" tip, i was not thinking about that right now, but its a good ideia, i will try to implement.
What i want is, compare the last “when” before and after user submit the comment, if its not the same after the submission and before post, user should be alerted.

Comment: You probably need to use an async javascript request for this, otherwise the use would need to submit the article twice, if I understand what you are saying correctly